# OS FLV Player - Modify Flash Player

Tags: flash

I have the [OS FLV player](http://www.osflv.com) emebedded on one of my websites.  I use it to play flash videos and it's really great.  The only problem is that I'd like to get rid of the big play button that appears in the middle prior to playing the video.  I can set one of the flash vars to autoplay and that gets rid of the button, but I'd like for the user to click the small play button in the corner and have a nice pre-image without the big play button in the middle of the screen.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to open the source file (.fla) and edit the actions of the player.  Now that I have done this....where do I post the modified source file?  I bet there are many people who would like to have this option.

Answer (score 0):

Do you own a copy of the Flash "IDE"? If not, looks like you're pretty stuffed. If you do, then find the "big play button" in the library, and remove any graphics from its library instance.

Comment: Then put the modified "source file" (.fla?) somewhere public, since OS FLV is GPL'd.

Comment: Spender.....your comment didn't provide me with the fix, but it put me on the right path.  Thank you.